# Swift 2: Error handling: throw: How to pass an object with an error?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

**How to pass the userInfo reference object when throwing an error in Swift2?**

Something like this would be good:

```
guard let refIDString = memberXMLElement.attributes["ref"] else {
     throw OSMVectorMapDescriptionError.ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes(userInfo:memberXMLElement)
}
```

And then:

```
catch OSMVectorMapDescriptionError.ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes {
  (userInfo:AnyObject) in
      //do stuff                 
 }
```

But errors are enums, we do can specify like here, but how to catch it?

```
public enum OSMVectorMapDescriptionError:ErrorType {
    case ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes(userInfo:AnyObject)
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget that you can `throw` the old good `NSError` as well. You can catch it via `catch let e as NSError` and then you can access user info via `e.userInfo` (this one was fixed in Xcode 7 beta 4, wasn't working in previous releases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need `someLevel`, you can define

```
public enum OSMVectorMapDescriptionError:ErrorType {
   case ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes(userInfo: ...)
}
```

use your guard unchanged

```
guard let refIDString = memberXMLElement.attributes["ref"] else {
    throw OSMVectorMapDescriptionError.
              ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes(userInfo:memberXMLElement)
}
```

and

```
catch OSMVectorMapDescriptionError.
          ElementDoesntContainRequiredAttributes(let userInfo) {
  //do stuff using userInfo              
}
```